# Replacing clip-path shape with SVG shape

Tags: html, css, svg, polygon

I currently have a polygon with text inside shown below

```css
.title {
  clip-path: polygon(1% 0, 100% 15%, 96% 90%, 0 75%);
  background-color: blue;
  
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  line-height: 50px;
  
  height: 60px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">&nbsp;&nbsp;WELCOME TO</h1>
```

I am looking for a more browser friendly version of this so I've been looking into using an SVG image. I'm struggling to nicely code this, as you see below I have the SVG shape, after a bit of testing, I quickly realised it doesn't scale well with the browser width. I would be happy if I could just keep it the same size all the time.

Then for the text after researching I learnt about the  tag inside an  tag, but even that I'm struggling to format the text.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 7 9" version="1">
      <polygon points=".1 0,5 .2,4.4 1.8,0 1.6" style="fill: #253234;" />
      <text x="1" y="1" fill="white" style="font-family:arial; font-size:.4">WELCOME TO</text>
    </svg>
```

Does anyone know of a better way of doing this, that works on major browsers and devices?

Answer (score 2):

if i were you i would try to achieve the same effect with only css using rotation for the container, inverting the text rotation with the same amount, then using a pseudo element (:after) with absolute positioning to achieve the non rectangular shape effect.

run the snippet for an example that you can adjust to fit your needs.

```css
.container {
  transform:rotate(3deg);
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  top:50px;
  padding:20px 30px 20px 20px;
  background-color:blue;
}
.container:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  background:white;
  width:20px;
  height:110%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:-10px;
  transform:rotate(10deg);
}
.title {
  color:#fff;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:18pt;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-family:arial;
  transform:rotate(-3deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><span class="title">Welcome to </span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the first and second version you gave differ so much, I am not that sure what it is you want to achieve. I'm going mostly with the first one.

The main trick is with the way you use the [`viewBox`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) attribute (and its accompaining [`preserveAspectRatio`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute)). Think of the `viewBox` as a rectangle that is fit into the area you define with `width` and `height`. (here, spelled out in CSS.) The `preserveAspectRatio` describes the fitting rule: choose the largest possible size for the rectangle that fits inside the element, and move it to the left and vertically to the middle.

Everything inside the `<svg>` now will remain fixed in position and proportion to that rectangle. If you raise the height of the element, the size of the text will grow; and if you lower its width, eventually it will shrink, but always together with the polygon.

I've positioned the text with `text-anchor: middle`, which is the equivalent of `text-align: center` for SVG. Using a font size of 0.4 as you did is not a good idea; browsers are prone to handle values below 1 incorrect.

Finally, if you are using this in place of a `<h1>` tag, you should either surround it with that to retain accessability, or set appropriate ARIA attributes as shown:

```css
.title {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block; /* not needed if surrounded by <h1> */
}

.title polygon {
  fill: blue;
}

.title text {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 24px;
    fill: #FFF;
    text-anchor: middle;
}
```

```html
<svg class="title" viewBox="0 0 250 60" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet"
     aria-role="heading" aria-level="1">
    <polygon points="2.5,0 250,9 240,54 0 45" />
    <text x="125" y="36">WELCOME TO</text>
</svg>
```